# Trying to pass URL variables into an iFrame on GoDaddy-hosted site

Tags: javascript, html, variables

we are currently using CognitoForms to host a form on our public-facing website. We have a need to pass a unique field called "barcode" on a per-user basis. I was hoping we could do something like https://ourwebsite.com/client?barcode=921371 but that doesn't seem to work at all.

After discussing with CognitoForms support, they provided the below script. However, it doesn't work from any browser. The browser console doesn't show any notable errors either. Is there something obviously incorrect here?

```
<iframe src="https://www.cognitoforms.com/f/ourformid/1" style="border:0;width:100%;" height="576">    </iframe>

<script src="https://www.cognitoforms.com/f/iframe.js"></script>

<script>
   function getQueryStringParam(parameter) {
      var queryString = window.location.search;
      var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      return urlParams.get(parameter);
   }
   Cognito.prefill({ "Barcode": getQueryStringParam('Barcode') });
</script>
```

I tried passing the parameters in different formats including JSON. I have also checked browser debug logs but can't find any errors - the field simply won't fill.

Answer (score 0):

Your example link references "**barcode**" as the query parameter:

https://ourwebsite.com/client?barcode=921371

The script references "**Barcode**"

```
Cognito.prefill({ "Barcode": getQueryStringParam('Barcode')
```

Isn't the error related to the wrong casing? ( "barcode" != "Barcode")

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I've tried the correct case, and it doesn't work either way